# XNA- Scale only parent

Tags: xna, c#, xna-4.0

I was wondering, is it possible to `Scale(Vector3)` a `ModelBone` without scaling its children. Lets say I got a **Bone A** at position `1,0,3`. And one of its children **Bone B** is at position `1,0,5` (he is touching **Bone A**). Could I scale **Bone A** along Z axis without scaling **Bone B**, but keep **Bone B** position and rotation so that he is still touching **Bone A**.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you scale the parent bone by factor A, scale the child by 1/A and it will keep the size.

Ej. if parent scale is multiplied by 2 you should mulptiply child scale by 1/2 = 0.5f

Comment: I am gonna go with your anwser, but only because it more suits my project. But thank you both.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo()`, it goes through the model's bone collection and applies parent SRTs to the children SRTs and places the results in a Matrix[]. So if after calling that, you then go into the resulting Matrix[], you could pick out BoneA's transform, apply some Z scale to it and it will not affect its children.

Notice you go into the resulting Matrix[] to do this, not the underlying model Bone collection. If you did this to BoneA's matrix in the underlying model bone collection, it would then apply that z scale to the children on the next frame when you again call `CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo()` and it doesn't sound like you want that.

Comment: Thanks! And sorry I cant upvote your anwser, I dont have enough reputation yet :/

Comment: btw, If I already have some <code>Matrix transform</code> should I apply scale like: <code> scale * transform </code> or any other way?

Comment: Also what is the correct way of multiplying existing matrix with rotation, and position.